# Replace NSWindow contentViewController with new ViewController with same Window Size

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

I need, on button click, to replace a NSWindow.contentViewController with new ViewController. To do this I wrote following code:

```
 let g = GameViewController()

 if self.window!.styleMask & NSFullScreenWindowMask != NSFullScreenWindowMask { 
    let ws = NSScreen.mainScreen()?.frame.size
    let width : CGFloat = g.view.frame.width
    let height : CGFloat = g.view.frame.height

    let frame = NSRect(origin: NSMakePoint(((ws?.width)!-width)/2, ((ws?.height)!-height)/2), size: CGSize(width:width, height:height))

    self.window?.setFrame(frame, display: true, animate: true)
}

self.window?.contentViewController = g
```

When NSWindow is not in FullScreen mode, this code works good. While, when NSWindow is in FullScreen mode, the GameViewController is set with his default size and not change is size until occurs a resize event.

How can I instantiate NSViewController in order to occupy all window space?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard:

```
let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                        if let homeViewController = (storyboard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController") as? NSViewController){
                            let windowController = NSWindowController(window: Constants.appDelegate!.window)
                            windowController.contentViewController = homeViewController
                            windowController.showWindow(Constants.appDelegate!.window)
                        }
```

Hope this will help you. Happy Codding

Comment: No, I'm not using Storyboard. I add all components programmatically.